# Insert large data in single time or every loop?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, insert

I have datas which are 3000+ rows. So previously I need to import this data to another tabe. SO previously I was doing it like below

```
<?php
foreach($datas as $data){
 //INSERT INTO table_name with $data 
 $con->query('insert query');
}

?>
```

Then I was thinking inserting each time consume some time by connecting to mysql and run insert queries though we have the connection created initially. So I tried to create the query first and then insert

So only one time mysql execution this avoids the each time connection and insert etc

```
<?php
foreach($datas as $data){
//INSERT INTO table_name with $data
//Concatenate each row and make single insert query with , separated values
}

//finally run the mysql insert with php
 $con->query('insert query');
//so only one time we call mysql server
?>
```

I like the second method but the problem is, if there is any one row data is not valid then the whole query fails.

If it is in the foreach insert then only the current row insert will fail other data will be insert.

**Is there a way to insert in bunch but if there is any single row data is not valid only that row alone shouldn't be insert and other rows should have been inserted in the table instead of whole query to fail?**

NOTE: I use `,` for the whole query values. 3000+ row data are small but I will be doing this often. That's why looking for a performance. above code is just the template not the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want performance, then minimize as much php interaction as possible. This means direct `LOAD DATA INFILE` or for pre-existing data from table to table, use sql-only movement. In other words, no PHP looping.

Concerning your comments to allow some to fail:

For data loads, use [`LOAD DATA INFILE IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html). Note the word `ingore`.

For pre-existing data movement, use `INSERT IGNORE`. Same as insert, just add ignore.

You will not beat this for performance compared to a PHP-driven loop approach.

Comment: Thank you I never thought about copying certain data from one table to another in mysql alone. Thanks for the new window. I'll try to do the copy from one table to another in single query and I'll execute it from php.

Comment: Here comes another doubt I need to copy from two tables from db X to single table in db Y. Is that possible in mysql alone? Also Insert Ignore is for avoid duplicate error my doubt was let say If there is no value for one column then there will be error in the query which will stop the whole execution Eg:`INSERT INTO table_nale (name,age,st) VALUES ("John","25","LA"),("George","dd"),("Edward","30","BB");` Since there is no age for the second row third row(edward) also won't be inserted

Comment: `insert ignore` keeps on trucking. If 3 fail and 511 succeed, all intermingled, the 511 make it. Depending on the nature of the tables and joins, there is no problem generally speaking of bringing data together from multiple tables, from multiple databases, and targeting a single other table (or a joined table) for the insert. The Devil's in the Details. So you need to describe the particulars of what you need to do, and determine the appropriate sql for it. Beginners sometimes use work tables to stage the whole thing if they cant figure it out to start (the fastest way).

Comment: Ya I am using some test table to practice Here is the query `INSERT IGNORE INTO fruit_cp (cp_id,name,price) VALUES (55,'pineapple',45),('mango',45),(35,'guva',12);` The query fails because mango doesn't have `cp_id` and thus fail the whole query. If  I do this in php with insert as each time then only the mango will get fail others will be inserted irrespective of mango fail

Comment: you have the rep to join the fun here in the [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) room. chat away